# Passing function, why is lambda required

Tags: python-2.7, timeit

I'm trying to use timeit to time an algorthm (reversing the string)
My question is about the signature of timeit.repeat

here is what i'm using, it is working fine

```
timeit.repeat(lambda: reverseString_perf(s), setup='pass', timer=timeit.default_timer,number=3)
```

my questions is - why can i not pass the function directly (as shown below)

```
timeit.repeat(reverseString_perf(s), setup='pass', timer=timeit.default_timer,number=3) #does not work
```

instead i'm having to pass `lambda:reverseString_perf(s)`
to get it to work.

there is no anonymous function here, so this is confusing usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reverseString_perf(s)` evaluates to the return value. If you passed in just `reverseString_perf`, it would work; however, you wouldn't be able to include the parameter in this case.

`lambda: reverseString_perf(s)` works because it is still a function, unlike `reverseString_perf(s)`, which is the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense !